# No Path found. Problem in accessing the file

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to create excel sheet and then store it in to my local device and after that i want to access that file to see my results. when i run the code it shows that your file is successfully saved and after that when i tries to open it then show no such file exist.

Error
I/flutter ( 7227): /data/user/0/com.example.aloha/app_flutter/DailyChecksForm_2023-12-10 14:23:43.032161.xlsx
I/flutter ( 7227): Error opening file: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method open_file on channel open_file)
Reloaded 1 of 1275 libraries in 1,406ms (compile: 81 ms, reload: 574 ms, reassemble: 583 ms).

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';
import 'package:excel/excel.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

class Logic {
  // Fields`your text`
  Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>> fieldData = {};
  late final String filePath;
  Future<void> generateExcelFile() async {
    // Get the application documents directory
    final Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;

    // Create the directory if it doesn't exist
    final Directory excelDir = Directory('$appDocPath/excel');
    if (!await excelDir.exists()) {
      await excelDir.create(recursive: true);
    }
    // automatically creates 1 empty sheet: Sheet1
    var excel = Excel.createExcel();
    Sheet sheet = excel['excel'];

    List rowData = ['Field', 'Answer', 'Note', 'Date'];

    // Add headers
    sheet.insertRowIterables(rowData, 1,
        startingColumn: 0, overwriteMergedCells: true);

    // Add data
    fieldData.forEach((field, data) {
      sheet.insertRowIterables(
          [field, data['answer'], data['note'], data['date']], 2);
    });

    // Save the Excel file
    //final Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    // final String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
    filePath =
        await '$appDocPath/DailyChecksForm_${DateTime.now().toString()}.xlsx';
    print(filePath);
    //await excel.save();

    // Share the Excel file
    //Share.shareFiles([filePath], text: 'Daily Checks Form Data');
    try {
      await excel.save();
      print('File saved successfully at: $filePath');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error saving file: $e');
      return; // Exit the function if there's an error saving the file
    }
  }

  getFile() async {
    // Share the Excel file
    /*try {
      await Share.shareFiles([filePath], text: 'Daily Checks Form Data');
      print('File shared successfully');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error sharing file: $e');
    }
    //Add headers
    // Share the Excel file
    try {
      final File file = File(filePath);
      await Share.shareFiles([file.path], text: 'Daily Checks Form Data');
      print('File shared successfully');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error sharing file: $e');
    }

    // Open the Excel file using open_file package
    try {
      await OpenFile.open(filePath);
      print('File opened successfully');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error opening file: $e');
    }*/
    try {
      await Share.shareXFiles([XFile(filePath)], text: 'Great picture');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error opening file: $e');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> > when i run the code it shows that your file is successfully saved

Then your code is wrong.

```
14:23:43.032161.xlsx
```

A `:` is a forbidden character for a file name so your file is not saved.